# Linking to stylesheet with Django

Tags: django

I've found a lot of different examples on how to do this, all slightly different in what they say to set as the MEDIA_URL, STATIC_URL, MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL. My project files are structured as follows:

```
myproject/
    images/ (user-uploaded)
    media/ (empty so far)
    settings.py
    static/
        css/
            styles.css
        fonts/
    templates/
        auth/
            base.html
            login.html
        index.html
    urls.py
```

And of course there's app directories in the root folder. For my images to show up on the index template, I did this:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

(r'%s(?P<path>.*)' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

settings.py (these were the default):

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

The site I'm making is on the front end just a single page. How do I get the stylesheet to link properly? I'm not really sure what the difference is between all these directory settings or why I would use one over another... or what the best way (if there is one) is to structure the whole thing, with where to put css, javascript, fonts, static images, user-uploaded images, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media is for user uploaded files, static - for your CSS and and other files, so you must create there directories for your static files like js and css.

You've done right all things, because something like this in official documentation in Django. I'll leave how my friend told me to do, to server static files in few machines:

```
# settings.py
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'models'))
PROJECT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = PROJECT_URL + '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = PROJECT_URL + '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = PROJECT_URL + '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media'),
)
# urls.py
urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

Comment: you don't even need the full URL path for `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL`, you can just use "/media/" and "/static/". Using os is definitely the best way to do it though.

Comment: ok, nevermind... don't know much Python but adding import os, sys at the top fixed it. What does that mean though, for deploying the site live? Will any of this be broken?

Comment: Yes, it was Python modules. As for this code - it will allow you to run your project at every computer in development mode, without redifinition of static directories - it will discover path in Windows or in Linux through Python functions.

Comment: And it will work at live project. This code is from my website, I develop it in Windows and now it is running on Linux (Ubuntu), and I need to change only PROJECT_URL to existing domain to make this running for me. But it is 'bad' way, your server must serve static files for you in live project, anyway this will work fine too. Since I'm not good at admining - I use this method.

Comment: @Art ...except now my 127.0.0.1:8000/admin styles are not linked anymore. How do I fix that?

Comment: Misterious thing ever. Just return your settings.py to start and then try replacing string by string from my code. Then you'll see where you need editions to make this run. I don't understand what I've done, nothing fix, but after that manipulations everything start work.

Comment: @Art It's trying to find the admin styles within my static directory. I just ended up copying & pasting the admin styles from my main Django directory into the project folder... I guess that works.

Comment: This solved my problem, and contrary to @j_syk's statement, the full path was needed for me to get the stylesheet to load.

Answer (score 3):

In pre-Django 1.3, there were just two settings that matter:

> **MEDIA_ROOT** : Absolute filesystem path to media files
>
> **MEDIA_URL** : Absolute URL to media files, with or without domain

Post-Django 1.3, the staticfiles contrib package was introduced, and it's pretty confusing for first-times. You need the following settings:

> **MEDIA_ROOT** : Absolute filesystem path to user uploads
>
> **MEDIA_URL** : Absolute URL to user uploads, with or without domain
>
> **STATIC_ROOT** : Absolute filesystem path to static files directory.
>   This is the folder used by the `collectstatic` management command.
>   DON'T manually put any files here.
>
> **STATIC_URL** : Absolute URL to static files directory, with or
>   without domain

Then, for each of your apps, you create a 'static' directory inside, and *this* is where your static files go. In development, Django automatically serves up these files under `STATIC_URL`. In production, you must run the `collectstatic` management command to have them all moved to the project's 'static' directory, which is then server under `STATIC_URL`.

That's all fine and good, but you may notice that this doesn't truly cover everything. There's always project-wide static files that don't necessarily belong to one app or another, yet the default staticfiles setup doesn't give you any place to put these. Therefore, you have take matters into your own hands with an additional setting:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/absolute/path/to/myproject/assets/",
)
```

Here, I've gone with a directory named 'assets', for project-wide static files. You can name the directory whatever you like, only it CANNOT be the same as `STATIC_ROOT`.

The last little bit that trips people up is serving admin media. All you have to do for that is include the setting:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL+'admin/'
```